# Parse JSON for data after keyword

Tags: json, google-sheets

I have some JSON data in Google Sheets that I wish to parse for the data after a keyword, eg:

"splashtopname":"DESKTOP-XXYYZZ"

This is in the middle of the JSON data which is delimited by commas eg:

"cpuidentifier":"Intel64 Family 6 Model 92 Stepping 9","splashtopname":"DESKTOP-XXYYZZ","splashtopversion":"3.4.6.2",

What I want to do is extract DESKTOP-XXYYZZ only from this (however this string length is variable and not fixed, nor does it always begin DESKTOP). I am stumped as to the formula to get this output, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `REGEXEXTRACT` should achieve your wanted data.

#### Formula:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, """splashtopname"":""([^""]*)""")`

Simply extract `<capture>` from pattern `"splashtopname":"<capture>"` via regex.

#### Output:

[image: output]